# Need help filtering output of a WordPress Plugin Class

Tags: php, wordpress, filter, action, hook

Below I have a class "WC_Deposits_Add_To_Cart". I want to edit the output of this class using add_filter in my functions.php.

The problem is I am a little confused on how to properly build my filter function to change the output of a class. I know how to filter functions but not classes.

Looking at the script it seems that the html syntax is not being returned nor echoed, and I see no variable being attached to the html output. I want to edit the output of the html syntax at the very bottom of the class.

For example the html starting at `<div id='wc-deposits-options-form'>` to the very last closing div on line 176.

**How would I go about doing this?**

I have been all over the wordpress codex and other forums but I have seen no examples of add_filte functions filter classes that output html like the one below.

Any guidance is appreciated.

```
<?php
/*Copyright: © 2014 Abdullah Ali.
License: GNU General Public License v3.0
License URI: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html
*/

if (!defined('ABSPATH')) {
  exit; // Exit if accessed directly
}

class WC_Deposits_Add_To_Cart
{
  public function __construct(&$wc_deposits)
  {
    // Add the required styles
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_scripts'));
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this, 'enqueue_inline_styles'));

    // Hook the add to cart form
    add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', array($this, 'before_add_to_cart_button'));
    add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', array($this, 'add_cart_item_data'), 10, 2);
  }

  /**
  * @brief Load the deposit-switch logic
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function enqueue_scripts()
  {
    if (is_product()) {
      global $post;
      $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);

      if ($product && isset($product->wc_deposits_enable_deposit) && $product->wc_deposits_enable_deposit === 'yes')
      {
        wp_enqueue_script('wc-deposits-add-to-cart', WC_DEPOSITS_PLUGIN_URL . '/assets/js/add-to-cart.js');

        $message_deposit = get_option('wc_deposits_message_deposit');
        $message_full_amount = get_option('wc_deposits_message_full_amount');

        $message_deposit = stripslashes($message_deposit);
        $message_full_amount = stripslashes($message_full_amount);

        $script_args = array(
          'message' => array(
            'deposit' => __($message_deposit, 'woocommerce-deposits'),
            'full' => __($message_full_amount, 'woocommerce-deposits')
          )
        );

        if ($product->is_type('variable') && $product->wc_deposits_amount_type !== 'fixed') {
          foreach($product->get_children() as $variation_id) {
            $variation = $product->get_child($variation_id);
            if (!is_object($variation)) continue;
            $tax = get_option('wc_deposits_tax_display', 'no') === 'yes' ?
              $variation->get_price_including_tax() - $variation->get_price_excluding_tax() : 0;
            $amount = woocommerce_price($variation->get_price_excluding_tax() *
              ($product->wc_deposits_deposit_amount / 100.0) + $tax);
            $script_args['variations'][$variation_id] = array($amount);
          }
        }

        wp_localize_script('wc-deposits-add-to-cart', 'wc_deposits_add_to_cart_options', $script_args);
      }
    }
  }

  /**
  * @brief Enqueues front-end styles
  *
  * @return void
  */
  public function enqueue_inline_styles()
  {
    if (is_product()) {
      global $post;
      $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);

      if ($product && isset($product->wc_deposits_enable_deposit) && $product->wc_deposits_enable_deposit === 'yes')
      {
        // prepare inline styles
        $colors = wc_deposits_woocommerce_frontend_colours();
        $gstart = $colors['primary'];
        $gend = wc_deposits_adjust_colour($colors['primary'], 15);

        $style = "@media only screen {
            #wc-deposits-options-form input.input-radio:enabled ~ label { color: {$colors['secondary']}; }
            #wc-deposits-options-form div a.wc-deposits-switcher {
              background-color: {$colors['primary']};
              background: -moz-gradient(center top, {$gstart} 0%, {$gend} 100%);
              background: -moz-linear-gradient(center top, {$gstart} 0%, {$gend} 100%);
              background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from({$gstart}), to({$gend}));
              background: -webkit-linear-gradient({$gstart}, {$gend});
              background: -o-linear-gradient({$gstart}, {$gend});
              background: linear-gradient({$gstart}, {$gend});
            }
            #wc-deposits-options-form .amount { color: {$colors['highlight']}; }
            #wc-deposits-options-form .deposit-option { display: inline; }
          }";

        wp_add_inline_style('wc-deposits-frontend-styles', $style);
      }
    }
  }

  public function before_add_to_cart_button()
  {
    global $product;
    if ($product && isset($product->wc_deposits_enable_deposit) && $product->wc_deposits_enable_deposit === 'yes')
    {
      $tax = get_option('wc_deposits_tax_display', 'no') === 'yes' ?
        $product->get_price_including_tax() - $product->get_price_excluding_tax() : 0;
      if ($product->wc_deposits_amount_type === 'fixed') {
        $amount = woocommerce_price($product->wc_deposits_deposit_amount + $tax);
        if ($product->is_type('booking') && $product->has_persons() && $product->wc_deposits_enable_per_person === 'yes') {
          $suffix = __('per person', 'woocommerce-deposits');
        } else if ($product->is_type('booking')) {
          $suffix = __('per booking', 'woocommerce-deposits');
        } else if (!$product->is_sold_individually()) {
          $suffix = __('per item', 'woocommerce-deposits');
        } else {
          $suffix = '';
        }
      } else {
        if ($product->is_type('booking')) {
          $amount = '<span class=\'amount\'>' . round($product->wc_deposits_deposit_amount, 2) . '%' . '</span>';
          $suffix = __('of total value', 'woocommerce-deposits');
        } else if ($product->is_type('variable')) {
          $min_variation = $product->get_child($product->min_price_variation_id);
          $max_variation = $product->get_child($product->max_price_variation_id);
          $tax_min = get_option('wc_deposits_tax_display', 'no') === 'yes' ? $min_variation->get_price_including_tax() - $min_variation->get_price_excluding_tax() : 0;
          $tax_max = get_option('wc_deposits_tax_display', 'no') === 'yes' ? $max_variation->get_price_including_tax() - $max_variation->get_price_excluding_tax() : 0;
          $amount_min = woocommerce_price($min_variation->get_price_excluding_tax() * ($product->wc_deposits_deposit_amount / 100.0) + $tax_min);
          $amount_max = woocommerce_price($max_variation->get_price_excluding_tax() * ($product->wc_deposits_deposit_amount / 100.0) + $tax_max);
          $amount = $amount_min . '&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;' . $amount_max;
        } else {
          $amount = woocommerce_price($product->get_price_excluding_tax() * ($product->wc_deposits_deposit_amount / 100.0) + $tax);
        }
        if (!$product->is_sold_individually()) {
          $suffix = __('per item', 'woocommerce-deposits');
        } else {
          $suffix = '';
        }
      }
      $default = get_option('wc_deposits_default_option', 'deposit');
      $deposit_checked = ($default === 'deposit' ? 'checked=\'checked\'' : '');
      $full_checked = ($default === 'full' ? 'checked=\'checked\'' : '');
      $deposit_text = get_option('wc_deposits_button_deposit');
      $full_text = get_option('wc_deposits_button_full_amount');
      if ($deposit_text === false) $deposit_text = __('Pay Deposit', 'woocommerce-deposits');
      if ($full_text === false) $full_text = __('Full Amount', 'woocommerce-deposits');
      $deposit_text = stripslashes($deposit_text);
      $full_text = stripslashes($full_text);
      ?>
        <div id='wc-deposits-options-form'>
          <hr class='separator' />
          <label class='deposit-option'>
            <?php echo __('Deposit Option:', 'woocommerce-deposits'); ?>
            <span id='deposit-amount'><?php echo $amount; ?></span>
            <span id='deposit-suffix'><?php echo $suffix; ?></span>
          </label>
          <div class="deposit-options switch-toggle switch-candy switch-woocommerce-deposits">
            <input id='pay-deposit' name='deposit-radio' type='radio' <?php echo $deposit_checked; ?> class='input-radio' value='deposit'>
            <label for='pay-deposit' onclick=''><span><?php _e($deposit_text, 'woocommerce-deposits'); ?></span></label>
          <?php if (isset($product->wc_deposits_force_deposit) && $product->wc_deposits_force_deposit === 'yes') { ?>
            <input id='pay-full-amount' name='deposit-radio' type='radio' class='input-radio' disabled>
            <label for='pay-full-amount' onclick=''><span><?php _e($full_text, 'woocommerce-deposits'); ?></span></label>
          <?php } else { ?>
            <input id='pay-full-amount' name='deposit-radio' type='radio' <?php echo $full_checked; ?> class='input-radio' value='full'>
            <label for='pay-full-amount' onclick=''><span><?php _e($full_text, 'woocommerce-deposits'); ?></span></label>
          <?php } ?>
            <a class='wc-deposits-switcher'></a>
          </div>
          <span class='deposit-message' id='wc-deposits-notice'></span>
        </div>
      <?php
    }
  }

  public function add_cart_item_data($cart_item_meta, $product_id)
  {
    $product = wc_get_product($product_id);
    if ($product->wc_deposits_enable_deposit === 'yes')
    {
      if (!isset($_POST['deposit-radio'])) {
        $default = get_option('wc_deposits_default_option');
        $_POST['deposit-radio'] = $default ? $default : 'deposit';
      }
      $cart_item_meta['deposit'] = array(
        'enable' => $product->wc_deposits_force_deposit === 'yes' ? 'yes' : ($_POST['deposit-radio'] === 'full' ? 'no' : 'yes')
      );
    }
    return $cart_item_meta;
  }
}
```

Here I am trying build my filter function in my functions.php

```
class WC_Deposits_Add_To_Cart {

    public function save_posts_hook() {
        return '<h1>My function works!</h1>';   
    }
}

$my_class = new WC_Deposits_Add_To_Cart; 
add_action( 'before_add_to_cart_button', array( $my_class, 'save_posts_hook' ) );
```

Comment: I want to change some of the way the input fields work in the html code. Which is why I am trying to filter out the html output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option could be to use output buffering.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'capture_add_to_cart_output_start', 9);
function capture_add_to_cart_output_start(){
    ob_start();
    add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'capture_add_to_cart_output', 11);
}
function capture_add_to_cart_output(){
    $html = ob_get_clean();
    $html = str_replace('deposit-options', 'deposit-options bootstrap_class', $html);
    echo $html;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Antony!! I am so close. I am able to filter out the html syntax but now the function of the script is duplicated, meaning there are two outputs. The original and the revised. Also, I get this error "Warning: Missing argument 1 for WC_Deposits_Add_To_Cart::__construct() " I think it is referring to `public function __construct(&$wc_deposits)`. What does this mean?

Comment: Are you using the code from this answer or the other one? It's referring to the construct and wants the $wc_deposits variable. The reason there is a duplicate is probably because the remove action needs to have the original instance of the class. Not just $my_class like you've got. One option is this `remove_all_actions( woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button, 10 ) https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_all_actions` What plugin are you using? I could probably help a lot easier with the whole plugin to look at.

Comment: The plugin I'm using is "WooCommerce.Deposits.Partial.Payments.Plugin.v1.4.2" I figured I had to use a different global variable. I've been trying to use the $wc_deposits variable but with no luck. I've been just reading through the code trying different class names and rearranging the remove_action function. Also, I read the priority of the remove_action function has to be the same as the add_action hook that called it the first time. I can send you the files of the plugin if you'd like. I still cant figure out how to remove the action :(

Comment: I think the problem is $wc_deposits is not a global variable so when I declare it in my functions.php, it is not being recognized.

Comment: Here is what I have so far in my functions.php `add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'custom_remove', 1 );

global $wc_deposits;

function custom_remove() {

    remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', array($wc_deposits, 'before_add_to_cart_button') );
}`

Comment: Thank you Antony for all your help. The remove_all_actions was the best method to solving this solution.

Comment: Awesome. Great to hear

Answer (score 0):

So did someone else write the WC_Deposits_Add_To_Cart class and your trying to hook into it?

Right now then class when created will output the html in the before_add_to_cart_button method.

You can see in the __construct method

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', array($this, 'before_add_to_cart_button'));
```

If you want to add some html before that html do this.

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'my_function_name', 1)
```

Or this to add html after

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'my_function_name', 11)
```

The third parameter there is the priority which decides the order the actions are fired, which by default is 10.

Update: If you want to override the output from that class, you can remove their action:

```
$my_class = new WC_Deposits_Add_To_Cart; 
remove_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', array($my_class, 'before_add_to_cart_button'));
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'new_html_output_function');
```

Note that your remove_action has to run after their class is initiated. One way to do this is add an action to `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button` which is sure to run after they added it, like shown above:

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'after_button', 1)
function after_button(){
    $my_class = new WC_Deposits_Add_To_Cart; 
    remove_action('woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', array($my_class, 'before_add_to_cart_button'));

    global $product;
    if ($product && isset($product->wc_deposits_enable_deposit) && $product->wc_deposits_enable_deposit === 'yes') {
        $tax = get_option('wc_deposits_tax_display', 'no') === 'yes' ? $product->get_price_including_tax() - $product->get_price_excluding_tax() : 0;
        if ($product->wc_deposits_amount_type === 'fixed') {
            $amount = woocommerce_price($product->wc_deposits_deposit_amount + $tax);
            if ($product->is_type('booking') && $product->has_persons() && $product->wc_deposits_enable_per_person === 'yes') {
                $suffix = __('per person', 'woocommerce-deposits');
            } else if ($product->is_type('booking')) {
                $suffix = __('per booking', 'woocommerce-deposits');
            } else if (!$product->is_sold_individually()) {
                $suffix = __('per item', 'woocommerce-deposits');
            } else {
                $suffix = '';
            }
        } else {
            if ($product->is_type('booking')) {
                $amount = '<span class=\'amount\'>' . round($product->wc_deposits_deposit_amount, 2) . '%' . '</span>';
                $suffix = __('of total value', 'woocommerce-deposits');
            } else if ($product->is_type('variable')) {
                $min_variation = $product->get_child($product->min_price_variation_id);
                $max_variation = $product->get_child($product->max_price_variation_id);
                $tax_min       = get_option('wc_deposits_tax_display', 'no') === 'yes' ? $min_variation->get_price_including_tax() - $min_variation->get_price_excluding_tax() : 0;
                $tax_max       = get_option('wc_deposits_tax_display', 'no') === 'yes' ? $max_variation->get_price_including_tax() - $max_variation->get_price_excluding_tax() : 0;
                $amount_min    = woocommerce_price($min_variation->get_price_excluding_tax() * ($product->wc_deposits_deposit_amount / 100.0) + $tax_min);
                $amount_max    = woocommerce_price($max_variation->get_price_excluding_tax() * ($product->wc_deposits_deposit_amount / 100.0) + $tax_max);
                $amount        = $amount_min . '&nbsp;&ndash;&nbsp;' . $amount_max;
            } else {
                $amount = woocommerce_price($product->get_price_excluding_tax() * ($product->wc_deposits_deposit_amount / 100.0) + $tax);
            }
            if (!$product->is_sold_individually()) {
                $suffix = __('per item', 'woocommerce-deposits');
            } else {
                $suffix = '';
            }
        }
        $default         = get_option('wc_deposits_default_option', 'deposit');
        $deposit_checked = ($default === 'deposit' ? 'checked=\'checked\'' : '');
        $full_checked    = ($default === 'full' ? 'checked=\'checked\'' : '');
        $deposit_text    = get_option('wc_deposits_button_deposit');
        $full_text       = get_option('wc_deposits_button_full_amount');
        if ($deposit_text === false)
            $deposit_text = __('Pay Deposit', 'woocommerce-deposits');
        if ($full_text === false)
            $full_text = __('Full Amount', 'woocommerce-deposits');
        $deposit_text = stripslashes($deposit_text);
        $full_text    = stripslashes($full_text);
    ?>
        <div id='wc-deposits-options-form'>
        <hr class='separator' />
        <label class='deposit-option'>
        <?php
        echo __('Deposit Option:', 'woocommerce-deposits');
    ?>
        <span id='deposit-amount'><?php
        echo $amount;
    ?></span>
        <span id='deposit-suffix'><?php
        echo $suffix;
    ?></span>
        </label>
        <div class="deposit-options switch-toggle switch-candy switch-woocommerce-deposits">
        <input id='pay-deposit' name='deposit-radio' type='radio' <?php
        echo $deposit_checked;
    ?> class='input-radio' value='deposit'>
        <label for='pay-deposit' onclick=''><span><?php
        _e($deposit_text, 'woocommerce-deposits');
    ?></span></label>
        <?php
        if (isset($product->wc_deposits_force_deposit) && $product->wc_deposits_force_deposit === 'yes') {
    ?>
        <input id='pay-full-amount' name='deposit-radio' type='radio' class='input-radio' disabled>
        <label for='pay-full-amount' onclick=''><span><?php
            _e($full_text, 'woocommerce-deposits');
    ?></span></label>
        <?php
        } else {
    ?>
        <input id='pay-full-amount' name='deposit-radio' type='radio' <?php
            echo $full_checked;
    ?> class='input-radio' value='full'>
        <label for='pay-full-amount' onclick=''><span><?php
            _e($full_text, 'woocommerce-deposits');
    ?></span></label>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
        <a class='wc-deposits-switcher'></a>
        </div>
        <span class='deposit-message' id='wc-deposits-notice'></span>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Antony for helping me out. Yes, this is a plugin that someone else wrote but if I figure out how to do this it will help me in the future.

Your comment though is a good reference for me in case I want to add code before or after.

Anyway, I do not want to exactly add html before or after. I want to edit the html code itself. I do not like some of the classes used and want to add some bootstrap classes. This is why I want to filter out the html.

Comment: You could still do that then. I'll update the answer

Comment: If this answers your question, can you accept the answer?

Comment: I appreciate your answer but it doesn't really answer my original question. I do not know how to properly filter the html code in the bottom of the script above.

Comment: Well the truth is the plugin hasn't offered a nice way. The way I just showed you is the only way. You need to completely remove their action and put all of their code in your own function and changed what you need to change. Or another possibly but dirty way would be to use output buffering. I can add another answer using that option if you like.

Comment: BTW, usually the way to customize a plugins output like your trying to do, the plugin developer needs to run the output through apply_filters. Then you could simply get all the HTML in a filter and do a find and replace.

Comment: I tried the code you gave me but the remove_action function does not work. The other add_action worked great but since the remove_action is not working, I now have duplicates.